# How to write the output of reducer once

Tags: java, hadoop

I am new to hadoop.While working on the samples I came to know that OutputCollector of reducer write the output(part-0000) for each key and value pair by appending it.

For eg:
    my k-v pair for reducer is `sachin#mumbai`
    then reducer will write at `part-0000 as sachin mumbai`
    Then other k-v pair is `rajni#chennai`
    then reducer append part-0000 as

```
 sachin mumbai
 rajni chennai
```

What my doubt is ..is it possible to write the output(all k-v pairs)only once

Comment: Why do you need this? I don't know if such a method exists, but I believe that you would need to use a buffer and store the whole output in memory, until there are no more values in the reduce method. Then, somehow, print the whole buffer at once. Maybe a stupid solution would be to append this output in one (or two, separating keys from values) String(s) and collect those as a single output key (and value). With Big Data, you would soon get out of memory...